# Javascript create new array object and assign new value

Tags: javascript

```
Hi I am getting problems to insert the marks in original array object from other array object.

Sample Input:-
```

The length of array can be increase up to n limit but the marks array will be same as of sample input length

```
let arr = [[
    {"name": 1, "task": 1}
    {"name": 1, "task": 2}
    {"name": 1, "task": 8}
    {"name": 1, "task": 9}
    ],
    [
    {"name": 1, "task": 3}
    {"name": 1, "task": 5}
    {"name": 1, "task": 6}
    {"name": 1, "task": 7}
    ]
]

I have to Insert the below listed marks in above object array as given in the output listed below after marksArr.

let marksArr = [
    {marks: 1},
    {marks: 2}
    {marks: 3}
    {marks: 4}
    {marks: 5}
    {marks: 6}
    {marks: 7}
    {marks: 8}
]
```

I was creating it like result[i][j] = {} but it is always showing the error of undefined j. So I am not able to detect the problem.

```
Output Array Object

let output = [[
    {"name": 1, "task": 1, "marks": 1}
    {"name": 1, "task": 2, "marks": 2}
    {"name": 1, "task": 8, "marks": 3}
    {"name": 1, "task": 9, "marks": 4}
    ],
    [
    {"name": 1, "task": 3, "marks": 5}
    {"name": 1, "task": 5, "marks": 6}
    {"name": 1, "task": 6, "marks": 7}
    {"name": 1, "task": 7, "marks": 8}
    ]
]
```

name, tasks already exists but I have to add the marks on the basis of marksArr. The sample output should have the structure given above in output object.

I am sorry if there is any problem in the data

Comment: Could you please add the code you tried till now.

Comment: Consider using `arr.map`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Array.map() method.

```
let output = Array(2)

output[0] = arr[0].map((item, index) => Object.assign({}, item, marksArr[index]))

output[1] = arr[1].map((item, index) => Object.assign({}, item, marksArr[index + 4]))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Array.prototype.map() 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
Merging Object 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#merging_objects